# Convert nested ArrayBuffer to nested Array in scala

Tags: scala

Is there any way to convert a nested `arrayBuffer` to a nested array in scala ? I tried using the `toArray` function, but it did not convert the nested `arrayBuffers`

I have an array buffer of type Any and following is my sample nested

```
ArrayBuffer(
ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(1, b), 5)))
```

Comment: what have you done so far? can you show the example?

Comment: `I have an array buffer of type Any ` This is probably an XY (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. You don't want to do that. Please explain a bit about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to write a nested arraybuffer to a dataframe. So for that I need to convert the arraybuffer to a nested seq so that I can pass it to a spark row

Comment: Here's the code I'm trying to use.
    def convert(a: Any): Array[Any] = a match {
    case ArrayBuffer(head @ ArrayBuffer(_*), tail @ ArrayBuffer(_*)) => 
    Array(Row.fromSeq(convert(head)), Row.fromSeq(convert(tail)))
    case ArrayBuffer(inner @ ArrayBuffer(_*)) => 
    Array(Row.fromSeq(convert(inner)))
    case ArrayBuffer(head @ ArrayBuffer(_*), tail @ _*) => 
    (Row.fromSeq(convert(head)) +: tail).toArray
    case arr @ ArrayBuffer(_*) => Row(arr.toArray).toSeq.toArray
    }
@TheArchetypalPaul

Comment: Edit the question.  But I'm not asking how you are trying to convert it, I'm asking why you think you need an array buffer of type Any in the first place. It's almost never a good idea to try to work with Any.

Comment: Because I have a nested ArrayBuffer whose size is not fixed. Hence, I am using ArrayBuffer of type any

Comment: That's not enough explanation (there's no problem having arraybuffers of arraybuffers of different lengths). The problem in your example is not the nested arraybuffers, it's the 5. If you changed it to ArrayBuffer(5) then you stop getting Any. I doubt you really need arraybuffers containing elements of different types. You need a better-matched data structure.

Comment: The datatypes of the entries in the array buffer are not predefined. There can be a string, int, double, etc. Hence, I am using any @TheArchetypalPaul

Comment: You are still not explaining why. But I give up. If you don't want to to use a datastructure that allows strong typing - and it is always possible to do that - iyou will have a difficult time as you are finding out. Data structures of Any are never a good idea

Comment: Well I don't know what else to use when you don't know the datatype. I wanted the function to accept data irrespective of the type.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for your specific test case. It converts nested `ArrayBuffer`s that are the first element of the enclosing `ArrayBuffer`:

```
def convert(a: Any): Array[Any] = a match {
  case ArrayBuffer(inner @ ArrayBuffer(_*)) => Array(convert(inner))
  case ArrayBuffer(head @ ArrayBuffer(_*), tail @ _*) => (convert(head) +: tail).toArray
  case arr @ ArrayBuffer(_*) => arr.toArray
}

val result = convert(ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(1, "b"), 5))))
// result is Array(Array(Array(Array(1, "b"), 5)))
```

Perhaps the above will help you come up with a more general solution.

Comment: I have posted the generic function. @chunjef

Answer (score 0):

I have created a generic function to convert arraybuffer to array.This takes care of nested arrayBuffers also

```
def convert(a: ArrayBuffer[Any]): Array[Any] = {

  val checkExistance = (x:ArrayBuffer[Any]) => x.zipWithIndex.collect{ case(x,y) if x.isInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]] => y}.toArray
  //filter(x => x.isInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]])
  val arr = checkExistance(a)
  for(i <- arr) {
    //if (a(i).isInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]]) {
    val m = a(i).asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]]
    if(checkExistance(m).length > 0) {
      a.update(i,(convert(m)).toArray)
    }
    else {
      val n = m.toArray
      a.update(i,n)
    }
  }
  a.toArray
}
```